# Выводит не весь список товаров

Tags: php, mysql

В базу сохраняю список выбранных товаров, в таблицу **zakazi** в ячейку `tovar` .

Запись в ячейке `tovar` имеет следующий вид: *2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4* - где 2, 4 и тд - ID товара.

Далее хочу вывести все эти товары:

```
$iddT = $tovar['tovar']; // имеет вид 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4

$catalog_tov = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tovari WHERE id IN (".$iddT.") ");
while ($tovar_c = mysql_fetch_assoc($catalog_tov))
{
  echo $tovar_c['id']."<br />"; //ID товара которые выводятся
}
```

В итоге на странице выводит только:

```
2
4
```

и все.

Вопрос, почему не выводит запись полностью, в моем случае так:

```
2
4
4
4
4
4
```

Поясню: несколько раз повторяется ID одного и того же товара - это для того чтобы узнать сколько штук этого товара пользователь заказал.

Comment: а почему должен? вы ставите всего-навсего условие фильтрации.

Comment: @Etki Не могли бы написать это условие в ответ? не совсем понял

Comment: В mysql результатом запроса не может быть несколько одних и тех же записей. Максимум одна

Comment: @Денис  IN ищет записи в теми ID которые в нем перечислены. И выводит разумеется каждую из записей только 1 раз. Почитайте в интернете про "Нормальная форма" и никогда не храните списки чего либо в одном поле.

Comment: @Денис А после того, как база будет _нормализована_ т.е. приведена хотя бы к 3 НФ, у вас товары к заказу будут лежать в отдельной таблице в виде отдельных строк, вы спокойно сделаете `select` сразу из 2х таблиц и получите все товары к заказу со всеми свойствами в нужном кол-ве. SQL  для того и предназначен, что бы выбирать _любую_ интересующую информацию _одним_ запросом с любыми условиями и соединениями нескольких таблиц. PS. И я бы рекомендовал все таки к заказу хранить товар-количество, а не 1,1,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас структура базы не соответствует даже 1 [нормальной форме](http://i-novice.net/6-normalnyx-form-bd/). Выборки из реляционных баз с такой структурой крайне сложны, потому как SQL рассчитан на работу с хоть сколько то нормализованными данными.

Но даже ваш вопрос можно решить чистым SQL, но с некоторыми извращениями. Для работы нам понадобится служебная таблица с порядковыми номерами, в ней должны подряд лежать записи `1,2,3,4,5 ...`. Количество записей в этой таблице должно быть заведомо больше, чем может быть ID заказов в вашей строке. В принципе можно было бы использовать любую таблицу с подходящим кол-вом записей, но я предпочитаю порядковые номера, такая таблица полезна в разных ситуациях. Назовем эту таблицу `seqnum` и занесем в нее 64 записи:

```
create table seqnum(X int not null);
insert into seqnum values(1);
insert into seqnum values(2);
insert into seqnum select X+2 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+4 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+8 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+16 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+32 from seqnum;
```

Далее мы делаем запрос, который выбирает вашу строку со списком 64 раза (кол-во записей в `seqnum`), выделяем из текущей строки первую id и на каждой итерации сокращаем строку на этот первый id. На всякий случай удаляем все пробелы. Ну и тут же переклеиваем ее с вашими товарами:

```
select *
  from (
   select trim(both " " from substr(@S,1,instr(@S,",")-1)) id,
          @S:=substr(@S,instr(@S,",")+1)
     from seqnum,(select @S:=concat("2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4",",") as S) S
    where @S!=""
  ) A,
  tovari B
 where B.id=A.id
```

Но и после этого наш запрос совершенно не оптимален, вы считаете записи средствами php, что в коре не верно, записи отлично может посчитать и сам MySQL:

```
select A.*,count(1) as cnt
  from (
   select trim(both " " from substr(@S,1,instr(@S,",")-1)) id,
          @S:=substr(@S,instr(@S,",")+1)
     from seqnum,(select @S:=concat("2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4",",") as S) S
    where @S!=""
  ) A,
  tovari B
 where B.id=A.id
 group by A.id
```

Этот запрос выдаст нам все колонки из таблицы товаров и в конце еще 1 колонку `cnt` с количеством таких товаров.

Все это я написал, что бы показать, что SQL умеет очень много, а не только `select * from table`, надо составить грамотную структуру базы, изучить поглубже SQL и любая работа с данными и разработка будет идти гораздо быстрее. Ваш запрос при правильной структуре базы, должен был выглядеть как то так (`zakTov` - таблица с id товара и количеством этого товара в заказе):

```
select A.*,B.cnt
  from tovari A, zakTov B
 where A.id=B.tov_id and B.zakaz_id=1
```

Согласитесь, выглядит явно проще, чем предыдущие разборы списка в строке.

Answer (score 1):

Вы своим запросом сообщаете СУБД следующее: "Дай мне все товары id, которых находится в множестве  {2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}"

Соответсвенно СУБД находит товар с id=4 и id=2. Других товаров просто нет.

Чтобы вывести товар столько раз, сколько он у вас в списке надо будет строку `2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4` разбить по запятым на массив при помощи `split()` и пройтись по этому массиву преобразуя строку-id в число ( `intval()`) и сравнивая с `id` в массиве выбранных товаров, который получили из базы (в данном случае только 2) - и выводить тот элемент, что совпал ( `intval(strid) == $tovar_c['id']`)

Хотя конечно, если есть возможсность сменить схему БД - сделайте это.