# Ошибка синтакса при использовании prepare в stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

В игре для Android пользователи могут залогиниться через Google+, Facebook, Twitter:

[image: app screenshot]

Каждый раз когда это мобильное приложение соединяется с MySQL/PHP бакэндом, оно шлет все известные ей social ids и я запоминаю их в колонку **sid** в таблице **social**:

```
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid    | varchar(180)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| given  | varchar(180)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| family | varchar(180)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city   | varchar(180)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| photo  | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| stamp  | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| uid    | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

А в таблице **users** я держу как бы настоящие user ids в колонке **uid** - и использую их повсюду в моей игре (для игровых партий, для банов, и в будущем для игровой статистики):

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| stamp         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| banned_until  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| banned_reason | varchar(180) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| medals        | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

И в моем PHP-скрипте я стараюсь соединить все social ids когда только представляется возможность:

для этого я нахожу **uids** для всех присланных мобильным приложением **sids**, а потом беру самое маленькое значение **uid** и прописываю его для всех записей в таблице **social**.

PHP-скрипт работает хорошо, но я пытаюсь передвинуть этот функционал в stored procedure (потому что позже мне придется менять **uid** в дюжине таблиц со статистикой).

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:**

По совету Майка (спасибо!), я стал использовать `@sql_1` вместо просто `sql_1`:

```
delimiter $$$

drop procedure if exists merge_users;
create procedure merge_users(IN in_sids varchar(255))
begin
        declare out_uid integer;

        set @sql_1 = concat('select min(uid) into out_uid from social where sid in (', in_sids, ')');
        prepare sth_1 from @sql_1;
        execute sth_1;
        deallocate prepare sth_1;

        IF found_rows() > 0 THEN -- поменяю позже на out_uid is not null

                set @sql_2 = concat('update social set uid=', out_uid, ' where sid in (', in_sids, ')');
                prepare sth_2 from @sql_2;
                execute sth_2;
                deallocate prepare sth_2;
        ELSE
                insert into farber_users(created, stamp, medals, green, red)
                values (unix_timestamp(), unix_timestamp(), 0, 0, 0);

                select last_insert_uid() into out_uid;

        END IF;

        select out_uid; -- почему-то не работает
end
$$$
```

К сожалению, при вызове все равно получаю ошибку:

```
# call merge_users("'sid1', 'sid2'");
ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: out_uid
```

И это странно, потому что у меня есть похожая процедура, где `select` в конце работает (он обязательно нужен мне, так как OUT parameter не работают с PHP и MySQL 5.6 из-за бага):

```
drop procedure if exists join_new_game;
create procedure join_new_game(IN in_uid integer,
                               IN in_letters varchar(130))
begin
        declare out_gid integer;

        start transaction;

        select gid into out_gid from games
        where (player1 = in_uid and stamp1 = 0)
        or (player2 = in_uid and stamp2 = 0) limit 1;

        IF found_rows() = 0 THEN

                select gid into out_gid from games
                where (player1 != in_uid and stamp1 > 0
                and player2 is null) limit 1;

                IF found_rows() > 0 THEN
                        update games set player2 = in_uid where gid = out_gid;
                ELSE

                        insert into games (created, player1, stamp1, stamp2, letters1, letters2, letters, board, style)
                        values (unix_timestamp(), in_uid, 0, 0, substring(in_letters, 1, 7), substring(in_letters, 8, 7), substring(in_letters, 15), space(225), 1);

                        select last_insert_id() into out_gid;
                END IF;
        END IF;

        select out_gid; -- работает OK, нужен для PHP workaround
        commit;
end
$$$
```

Comment: Судя по всему для хранения _текста_ sql запроса надо использовать переменные с `@`, а не обычные переменные хранимых процедур. (`prepare sth1 for @sql1`) Так по крайней мере во всех примерах в интернете. И имейте ввиду, что `select min(uid)` _всегда_ возвращает одну строку, вне зависимости от того, будут найдены строки в social или нет. Так что рекомендую проверять не количество строк, а `out_uid is not null`. И еще надо убедится, что динамический запрос сможет выбрать в переменную хранимой процедуры. Я не в курсе этого, но интуиция подсказывает мне ждать подводных камней

Comment: Кошмар, я тоскую по PostgreSQL - но для этого проекта вынужден использовать MySQL (потому что планирую использовать Wordpress на игровом сайте).

Comment: Ну никто не мешает держать основные данные игры в postgress, а то что нужно для сайта на wordpress в MySQL. А такое средство как "Oracle golden gate" может наладить онлайн репликацию между различными БД, правда с ним повозится надо для настройки и отладить что бы оно автоматом работало. Ну это если совсем грустно станет :) А так у mysql есть по возможностям синтаксиса и функциям плюсы по сравнению с postgress, правда отсутствие рекурсивынх запросов и оконных функций тут же все остальные плюсы делают сомнительными :)

Comment: И еще в связи с фразой `потому что позже мне придется менять uid в дюжине таблиц со статистикой` мне кажется над структурой базы надо еще поработать... Например в social сделать primary все таки id типа int, а не некий sid, который еще между разными социальными сетями может вдруг пересечься. sid сделать вторым полем. И во всей статистике держать только свой короткий id и соотв. uid к нему всегда выбирать через social, а не писать его еще в кучу таблиц

Comment: Спасибо, но **sid** - это строчка с id пользователя соц. сети - ее присылают все (Facebook, Vkontakte, Odnoklassniki, ...) и она нужна мне в игре, по ней я буду узнавать игроков.

Comment: Я понимаю. но что если face и vk например сделают одинаковые sid ? они то поддерживают уникальность только внутри себя. поэтому я и предлагаю сделать свой сурогатный ключ для этих записей, а sid сделать отдельным полем уникальность которого поддерживать вкупе с полем "тип соцсети"

Comment: Я перешел по Вашему совету на использование `@sql_1` и `@sql_2` - но теперь почему-то получаю ошибку, что мол `out_uid` не найдена...

Comment: Я же говорил: _И еще надо убедится, что динамический запрос сможет выбрать в переменную хранимой процедуры. Я не в курсе этого, но интуиция подсказывает мне ждать подводных камней_  Значит они есть ... Попробуйте то же переменную с @ использовать. они вроде в сессии живут между отдельными запросами, может и тут получится

Comment: Увы, `@out_uid` тоже не работает: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'out_uid' in 'field list'`. Может быть есть другой способ передать моей процедуре список строчек **sids**? (не как сейчас, где я пытаюсь передать 1 строку вида `'sid1', 'sid2, 'sid3'`) и потом динамически сконструировать из нее 2 SQL-запроса.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591338/my-sql-dynamic-query-execute-and-get-ouput-into-a-variable-in-stored-procedure   Я как только ваш вопрос увидел, думал можно ли как то без динамики ... И ничего не придумал. Ну т.е. в принципе развернуть список из текстовой строки конечно можно ... но там изврат еще тот будет ...

Comment: Вот, нашел, я ответ писал по поиску из строки разделенной запятыми. можно для вашего случая приспособить. но как я и говорил, изврат конечно... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478323/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/478349#478349